# c# assign 1 dimensional array to 2 dimensional array with shifting values

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a vector (1D array) of double values, say X. I need to copy this vector of values into a matrix (2D array), say Y, such that the first row of Y is the same as X transposed, the second row is the same as X shifted one value to the left, the third row of Y is the same as X shifted two values to the left and so on.

For example,

```
X = { 1.0, 2.0. 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 }
```

and I need

```
Y =  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
     2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  0.0
     3.0  4.0  5.0  0.0  0.0
     4.0  5.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
     5.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Some time ago Mathew Finlay posted code for copying 1D array to a 2D array for value types. I have modified the code as follows:

```
for (int targetRow = 0; targetRow < N; targetRow++)
{
    Buffer.BlockCopy
    (
        X,                                                    // 1D source array
        0,                                                    // source array offset
        Y,                                                    // 2D target (destination) array
        targetRow * Y.GetLength(targetRow) * sizeof(double),  // target array offset
        X.Length * sizeof(double)                             // count
    );
}
```

I am not sure if this will do the trick and more importantly, whether this is the best way of doing this. This is part of a larger code and this part needs to be fast and efficient as the vector X and the matrix Y can get very large.

Also, to complicate things a bit more, I may sometines not require the full length (all the values) of vector X but only part of it so the matrix Y could be N x M where M <= N. I am not sure how to handle this in the code above.

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions you may be able to provide.

EDIT:
For those interested, here are some performance results.

I ran some speed tests on the two types of code suggested here (looping and Buffer.BlockCopy) and the results surprised me. I will designate the Buffer.BlockCopy as BC and looping as L. For 10x10 matrix BC = 00:00:00.0000017 and L = 00:00:00.0000030. For 100x100 matrix BC = 00:00:00.0000293 and L = 00:00:00.0000710. Finally, for 1000x1000 matrix BC = 00:00:00.0065340 and L = 00:00:00.0138396. So the Buffer.Block copy seems to outperform looping even for small matrices. I ran this on a Win 7 Ultimate (64) machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about?

```
       double[] X = new double[]{ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 };

        var lbound = X.GetLowerBound(0);
        var ubound = X.GetUpperBound(0);

       double[,] Y = new double[ubound + 1, ubound + 1];

       for (var i = lbound; i <= ubound; i++)
       {
           for (var j = lbound ; j <= ubound ; j++)
           {
               Y[i, j] = (i + j) > ubound ? 0.0 : X[i +j];
           }  
       }
```

---

*Edit*

This works:

```
 for (int targetRow = 0; targetRow <= ubound; targetRow++)
  {
    Buffer.BlockCopy
    (
        X,                                        // 1D source array
        targetRow * sizeof(double),               // source array offset
        Y,                                        // 2D target (destination) array
        (targetRow * X.Length) * sizeof(double),  // target array offset
        (X.Length - targetRow) * sizeof(double)  // count
    );
}


for (var i = 0; i <= ubound; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j <= ubound; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(Y[i, j] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

[image: Array Offset]

---

*2nd Edit*

To deal with your other requirement of changing 2nd dimension of the destination array, you need to change some of the `BlockCopy` parameters `targetArrayOffset` and `count`, you can map them to the dimension of the destination array as below.

```
        double[] X = new double[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0 };

        var lbound = X.GetLowerBound(0);
        var ubound = X.GetUpperBound(0);

       double[,] Y = new double[X.Length, 3];

        int yLen = Y.GetUpperBound(1) + 1;

for (int targetRow = 0; targetRow <= ubound; targetRow++)
{
    Buffer.BlockCopy
    (
        X,                                      // 1D source array
        (targetRow * sizeof(double)),             // source array offset
        Y,                                        // 2D target (destination) array
        ((targetRow * yLen) * sizeof(double)),// target array offset
        ((X.Length - targetRow) > yLen ? yLen : (X.Length - targetRow))  * sizeof(double)  // count
    );
}
```

output:

[image: ScreenPrint]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am trying to stay away from looping for speed purposes. I thought I could simply adjust the offsets in the Buffer.BlockCopy to get this done efficiently.

Comment: @PBrenek I found a way of using `Buffer.BlockCopy` to achieve what you want. I don't know how practical it is though....

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I really do appreciate it. This is actually quite interesting. Unfortunately, as pointed out by Jeppe Stig Nielsen below, there is a 2GB limit on the size of an array and your approach of using Buffer.BlockCopy would require the array size to be doubled - due to the zero padding. This would effectively reduce the number of values to analyze by half. It appears I may need to use looping rather than Buffer.BlockCopy. Thank you very much anyways.

Comment: @PBrenek I updated my answer and figured out how to do it without doubling the array size :-)

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you very much. There is unfortunately one glitch. This method works to create a square matrix. There are times, however, where the matrix is not square. So using your example, I need the 10 rows but only a variable number of columns, less than or equal 10. So imagine that the output is as above but only with say 6 or 7 columns. I will try adjusting the ubound in the for loop.

Comment: @PBrenek I think that you should be looking at the last parameter of the `BlockCopy` function rather than `ubound`. You should be able to use the upper bound of your destination array rather than `X.Length`. Glad I could help.

Comment: I tried the revised method but it does not seem to generate the matrix correctly.

Comment: @PBrenek I've added another example to show the change you can make and another example output demonstrating.. I think this is right...

Comment: This is fantastic and works. Thank you very much. It is much appreciated. The only minor concern I have is the logical test expression in the count of the BlockCopy and its impact on performance. However, thank you very much.

Comment: @PBrenek I thought the same thing, but couldn't think of a way round it.. Maybe you should run some tests against if it performs better than the looping. If you do, let me know the results, I would be interested.

Comment: I will run some performance tests and check it out. Thank you nonetheless.

Comment: I ran some speed tests on the code and the results surprised me. I will designate the Buffer.BlockCopy as BC and looping as L. For 10x10 matrix BC = 00:00:00.0000017 and L = 00:00:00.0000030. For 100x100 matrix BC = 00:00:00.0000293 and L = 00:00:00.0000710. Finally, for 1000x1000 matrix BC = 00:00:00.0065340 and L = 00:00:00.0138396. So the Buffer.Block copy seems to outperform looping even for small matrices. I ran this on a Win 7 Ultimate (64) machine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Wow. That is quite a difference. It may be worth adding that info to the bottom of your question so that it's available if anyone else stumbles across this thread.

Comment: I would happily add the info but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: You should see `share|edit|flag` on the bottom left hand corner of your question. Just click edit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `x` is of type `double[]`, use:

```
var y = new double[x.Length, x.Length];
for (int row = 0; row < x.Length; ++row)
{
  for (int col = 0; col < x.Length - row; ++col)
  {
    y[row, col] = x[col - row];
  }
}
```

or similar.

Comment: I will check this out. Thank you. I was under the impression that Buffer.BlockCopy was much faster than looping so I was hoping to use it instead of looping and just adjust the offsets.

Comment: @PBrenek Looping is extremely fast. Memory access should be extremely fast as well. How huge are your arrays?

Comment: It is hard to say because there is no upper limit and the size is determined by the user but it could easily be 1,000,000 x 1,000,000.

Comment: @PBrenek That's one million million entries. Each `double` is eight bytes. So it would be **eight terabytes** in total. Sure you have enough memory? (Actually no array can be over two gigabytes in .NET.)

Comment: Hmm. I did not think of that. I may need to put in an upper limit. However, the point I was hoping to convey is that the matrices could be large enough for Memory copy to perform significantly better than looping. Thanks for the heads up on the memory size issue.